# Return Filter Quadrants for Search Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Working on a search page.  My search results are working but I also need to provide filter choices.  One of these choices are a set of price quadrants with product counts.  So basically in the result set I have to grab the lowest price and the highest price, then equally break it into 4 groupings and then return those groupings with product counts for each.

So we returned back 49 products, the lowest priced product was $10 and the highest priced products was $110.  I have to re-calculate this for every set of search results we're filtering so I can't hard code the floor and ceiling values.

So it would look like this with the number in parenthesis being the number of returned products with a value falling inside that quadrant.

```
$10.00 to $35.00  (2)
$35.01 to $60.00 (12)
$60.01 to $85.00 (0)
$85.01 to $110.00  (35)
```

I'm trying to do this in a single SELECT statement because we want to run it off the search results temporary table if the user asks for it.

I keep hitting brick walls trying to write this and can't seem to get very far.

Comment: In all likelihood, people want to see you make an attempt before they rush to write code for you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided details such as the schema of the table involved, a sample query that doesn't work, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work in a single statement, but I was able to get it to work.  We created a Numbers table called [Numbers] that I'm using...

```
DECLARE @priceFloor money; DECLARE @priceCeiling money; DECLARE @priceRange int;  
SELECT @PriceFloor = FLOOR(MIN(price)) , @PriceCeiling = CEILING(Max(price)),
    @PriceRange = CEILING(Max(price))/4 
FROM #TempSearchResults;  

WITH priceFilterCTE AS
(          
    SELECT Number * @PriceRange AS FromPrice, (Number * @PriceRange) + @PriceRange -.01 AS ToPrice          
    FROM Numbers 
    WHERE Number BETWEEN 0 AND 3 
)  

SELECT CAST(FromPrice AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' to ' + CAST(ToPrice AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Price,  
    (
       SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM #TempSearchResults 
       WHERE price BETWEEN  priceFilterCTE.FromPrice AND priceFilterCTE.ToPrice
    ) AS [COUNT]  
FROM priceFilterCTE
```

Return looks like....

```
PRICE             COUNT
0 to 798.99       949
799 to 1597.99    162
1598 to 2396.99   32
2397 to 3195.99   7
```